# How can i send an image from php to android, using volley and Json

Tags: php, android, json, image, bitmap

im trying to load an image that i need to load from a server, 
I have 3 questions:

1. I don't know how i can convert the images in bitmaps (this in the server side)
2. How to convert this bitmap in a image (this in the android side).
3. How can i send this bitmap with volley request.

I am using volley to make the request.
The server method that i have is this:

```
function getImage($image_path){
    $base ='images/practices/'.$image_path;
        $binary=base64_encode($base);
        $resp['image_binary']= $binary;
        print_r(json_encode($resp));
}
```

The method that I am using to do the other requests is:

```
String url = "---------";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                        //here the processing of the response...
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("error",""+error.toString());
                }
            }
    );
    VolleyS.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: You can try Glide[https://github.com/bumptech/glide] or you can use picasso[https://github.com/square/picasso]

Answer (score 2):

Try
 [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

or [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Its simple and easy

Answer (score 1):

1. Store the images in a folder on your server.
2. Store the name of the image in your DB
3. User Picasso/Imageloader/Glide libraries to load the image.
4. Pass the image url to the above libraries like this:- http://www.yourservername.com/imageFolderName/ImageName.jpj
5. The image name comes from your JSON/XML response and simple append it the path like above

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following Libraries

1. [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) By simply adding

Following Script to your app Gradle file

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // jcenter() works as well because it pulls from Maven Central
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

And then you can simply use the library like this in your activity

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load("<Image URL>").into(imageView);
```

2. [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) By simply adding 
   Following script to your app Gradle file

`compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'`

And use it into activity like this

```
Picasso.with(context).load("<image-url>").into(imageView);
```

Comment: I have proved it, but i cant get the image from a url, i need a controler in php which is the responsible for sending the image. (in bitmap or i don't know how).

Answer (score 0):

Convert file to base64

```
// 1 convert file to inputStream
// 2 wrap inputStream into byteArrayOutputStream
// 3 transform byteArrayOutputStream to byte array
// 4 convert byte array to Base64 object and return
public String mEncode(String filename) {
    int bytesRead;
    byte[] bytes = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; // buffer
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Convert base64 to file

```
public static boolean convertCode2Image(String imageBase64Code, String filePath) {
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        // Converting a Base64 String into Image byte array
        byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.decodeBase64(imageDataString);
        // Write a image byte array into file system
        FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);
        imageOutFile.close();
        success = true;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        printError("Image not found" + e);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        printError("Exception while reading the Image " + ioe);
    }
    return success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this in googledevelopers, i will prove it when i be able to send a bitmap from php.

`String URL= "http://image_url.png";
   ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
               // Assign the response to an ImageView
               ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(response);
           }
       }, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
              Log.d(TAG , error.toString());
           }
       });
    //add request to queue
    queue.add(imageRequest);`

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

In Android:

```
String imagepath = response.getString("path");
String url = "YOUR-URL";
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.YOURIMAGEVIEW);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}, 0, 0, null,
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagepractice);
        mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sq_br_down);
    }
});
VolleyS.getInstance(PracticeActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

And in the PHP server:

```
function getImage($image){
    if(strpos($image,'png')){
        $im = imagecreatefrompng('images/'.$image);
        header('Conten-Type: image/png');
        imagepng($im);
    }else if(strpos($image,'jpeg')){
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/'.$image);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($im);
    }else if(strpos($image,'jpg')){
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/'.$image);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($im);
    }else{
        $im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
        $color_texto = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
        imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'ERROR', $color_texto);
        header('Conten-Type: image/vnd.wap.wbmp');
        imagewbmp($im);
    }
    imagedestroy($im);
}`
```